# How to send agents from an `Exit` block to another `Enter` block

Tags: anylogic

How should I formulate a function that passes the agent from Exit to Enter?
[image: Screenshot of the function]

Answer (score 0):

> how should I formulate a function that passes the agent from Exit to Enter?

In the `Exit` block, write `myEnterBlock.take(agent);`. This takes the exiting agent to the enter block named `myEnterBlock`

> I just haven't yet understood what I have to consider with functions in anyLogic.

Nothing special about AnyLogic, this is just programming in Java. So start learning the basics of OOP programming, do *ALL* the AnyLogic tutorials and you will slowly get a grip. Also, some online beginner courses will be helpful, see Udemy or Teachable.

Last, pls understand how to best [leverage the AnyLogic community](https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community).